# Sending emails to subgroups/supergroups - Nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the file with following records. This represents group'name:emailadd'

```
Group1: it@group.foobar.com, Group1: it@group.foobar.com  
Group2: man@foobar.com, Group2: man@foobar.com  
Group3: xyz@foobar.com, test-grp: yz@foobar.com, grp-t: new@foobar.com, test-contract: new_g@foobar.com, grp0: ij@foobar.com, grp8: turu@foobar.com  
Group_test: iu@foobar.com, gvgrp: in@foobar.com, rsgrp: ij@foobar.com, dev: mp@foobar.com, rs: uru@foobar.com
```

Assume very first field:email is supergrpup and other is nested groups
that means

Supegroups:

```
Group1: it@group.foobar.com  
Group2: man@foobar.com   
Group3: xyz@foobar.com  
Group_test: iu@foobar.com
```

Subgroups:

```
Group1: it@group.foobar.com 
Group2: man@foobar.com
test-grp: yz@foobar.com, grp-t: new@foobar.com, test-contract: new_g@foobar.com, grp0: ij@foobar.com, grp8: turu@foobar.com 
gvgrp: in@foobar.com, rsgrp: ij@foobar.com, dev: mp@foobar.com, rs: uru@foobar.com
```

Now I want to send email to these groups to address ( separated by ':')

But the email should be send to supergroups and its respective subgroups

Like for  line:

```
  Group3: xyz@foobar.com, test-grp: yz@foobar.com, grp-t: new@foobar.com, test-contract: new_g@foobar.com, grp0: ij@foobar.com, grp8: turu@foobar.com
```

It should send email to supergroup email and all subgroups email address and use their  groupnames in body of email.

---

```
To: xyz@foobar.com, yz@foobar.com, new@foobar.com, new_g@foobar.com, 
ij@foobar.com,  turu@foobar.com 

Body:
Failed because of groupnames :  Group3, test-grp, grp-t, test-contract, 
grp0, grp8 ---------> These are all  group associated with email specified 
in "To":
```

I am not sure how I should do that? I was trying to create dictionaries but again its not working...

It would be great help , if someone can have a look and help me out?

Many thanks
Bob

Comment: where is the code? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string with regex and group to create a list of nested dictionaries:

```
import re
s = """
Group1: it@group.foobar.com, Group1: it@group.foobar.com  
Group2: man@foobar.com, Group2: man@foobar.com  
Group3: xyz@foobar.com, test-grp: yz@foobar.com, grp-t: new@foobar.com, test-contract: new_g@foobar.com, grp0: ij@foobar.com, grp8: turu@foobar.com  
Group_test: iu@foobar.com, gvgrp: in@foobar.com, rsgrp: ij@foobar.com, dev: mp@foobar.com, rs: uru@foobar.com
"""
listings = [re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+(?=:\s)|(?<=:\s)[a-zA-Z0-9@\._]+', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]
new_groups = [{**{i[0]:i[1]}, **{'subgroups':dict([(i[2:][b], i[2:][b+1]) for b in range(0, len(i)-2, 2)])}} for i in listings]
def get_flattened_listing(d):
   return [i for b in [[b] if not isinstance(b, dict) else get_flattened_listing(b) for a, b in d.items()] for i in b]

def send_email(structure, body='Testing new system'):
   yield from ['To: {}\n\nBody: {}'.format(', '.join(get_flattened_listing(i)), body) for i in structure]

for message in send_email(new_groups):
  print(message)
  print('-'*10)
```

Output:

```
To: it@group.foobar.com, it@group.foobar.com

Body: Testing new system
----------
To: man@foobar.com, man@foobar.com

Body: Testing new system
----------
To: xyz@foobar.com, yz@foobar.com, new@foobar.com, new_g@foobar.com, ij@foobar.com, turu@foobar.com

Body: Testing new system
----------
To: iu@foobar.com, in@foobar.com, ij@foobar.com, mp@foobar.com, uru@foobar.com

Body: Testing new system
----------
```

Comment: Thanks for help...I really appreciate that